# How to set ng-model to parent scope with a dynamic value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to dynamically generate a name for the ng-model on the select tags, and have it accessible in the parent scope like on table two, but obviously have them work independent of each other.

So my question is how do I set the ng-model to something like "$parent.ot1" data array of objects?

```js
 var overtimeapp = angular.module('overtime', []);

      overtimeapp.controller('ctrlOvertime', function ($scope, $http) {
        
        $scope.overtimes = [{"otid" : "ot1"}, {"otid" : "ot2"}];

        $scope.overtimetypes = ['d', 'n', 'r', 's', 'h'];
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="overtime" ng-controller="ctrlOvertime">
   table one
   <table class="table table-bordered">
     <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="o in overtimes">
   <td>
     <select class="w3-select" ng-model="o.otid" ng-options="x for x in  
                overtimetypes"></select>
   </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
   </table>
          table two
   <table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="o in overtimes">
      <td>
     <select class="w3-select" ng-model="$parent.selected" ng-options="x for x in  
                overtimetypes"></select>
   </td>
    </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `$scope.selected` as an array in the controller:

```
$scope.selected = [];
```

Then use `$index` in the `ng-model` directive:

```
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="o in overtimes">
        <td>
          <select class="w3-select"
                  ̶n̶g̶-̶m̶o̶d̶e̶l̶=̶"̶$̶p̶a̶r̶e̶n̶t̶.̶s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶"̶
                  ng-model="selected[$index]"
                  ng-options="x for x in overtimetypes">
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```